# DROP TABLE by CONCAT table name with VALUE from another SELECT [SQLite]

Tags: sql, sqlite

I was wondering how can I drop table with concat by selecting value from other table.
This is what I am trying to figure out:

```
DROP TABLE SELECT 'table' || (select value from IncrementTable)
```

So basically table name is table6 for example.
Goal is: eg.. `DROP TABLE table6`

Comment: which programming language you are using to connect to SQLLITE ?

Comment: I am using a batch script to execute sqlite.exe and execute statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this directly. Table and column names have to be known when the statement is byte-compiled; they can't be generated at runtime. You have to figure out the table name and generate the appropriate statement string in the program using the database, and execute it.